# make not run onItemSelected after reset spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I have 3 spinner in my app, and I set all by

```
    spinner_1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()

        {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, 
        int arg2, long arg3)

        {
            run_function_A();   
        }

        });

spinner_3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()

        {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, 
        int arg2, long arg3)

        {
            run_function_B();   
        }

        });

spinner_1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()

        {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, 
        int arg2, long arg3)

        {
            run_functionC();    
        }

        });
```

Code above, look run function if Spinner Selected item, but
i want to reset all spinner with button like this

```
clear_all_spinner.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                spinner_1.setSelection(0);
                spinner_2.setSelection(0);
                spinner_3.setSelection(0);

            }
        });
```

I want after all reset with not running run_function_A(),run_function_B(),run_function_C() .. how the way?

Comment: Can you be more specify on your question.

Comment: do you want to disable your spinner?

Comment: please check again, sorry for english

Answer (score 0):

you can try setting setOnItemSelectedListener(null) on all spinner before resetting the default selected item to the one at zeroth index and then setOnItemSelectedListener back to the one you set. I have modified you code as below:

```
clear_all_spinner.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            spinner_1.setOnItemSelectedListener(null);
            spinner_2.setOnItemSelectedListener(null);
            spinner_3.setOnItemSelectedListener(null);
            spinner_1.setSelection(0);
            spinner_2.setSelection(0);
            spinner_3.setSelection(0);
            spinner_1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
            {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, 
                        int arg2, long arg3)

                {
                    run_function_A();   
                }

            });

            spinner_3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()

            {

                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, 
                        int arg2, long arg3)

                {
                    run_function_B();   
                }

            });

            spinner_1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()

            {

                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, 
                        int arg2, long arg3)

                {
                    run_functionC();    
                }

            });
        }
    });
```

Also i see one bug in your code, you are setting setOnItemSelectedListener for spinner_1 twice ... see run_functionA() and run_functionC() are both set for spinner_1 selection. i have copied your code as it but you need to modify it.

It would be better to set the code of setting up ItemSelectedListener in a method block so instead of writing the same code at two places, you can simply call the method.